# Getting null pointer exception at sqlite query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Getting a null pointer exception at squlite query.

Following is my code snippet

```
String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;     
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    if(checkDB != null){
    Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT Id, UserName FROM Login Where status="+ 1, null);
        if(cursor != null ) {
            if  (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                String UserName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("UserName"));
                String mail_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("status"));
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserAccount.class);

                /*Sending some arguments*/ 
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                  bundle.putString("UserName",UserName);
                  bundle.putString("Id", mail_id);
                  intent.putExtras(bundle);
                  startActivity(intent);
```

When I debugged the code, I have got a path value in checkDB variable but cursor value is null. So that I have getting null pointer exception at the line

```
        Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT Id, UserName FROM Login Where status="+ 1, null);
```

I couldn't find the source of reason, Please help me...

Comment: If you change to `Cursor  cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT Id, UserName FROM Login Where status=1", null);` does it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the "database" variable initialized, because seems like what you should be using is "checkDB", maybe database variable is null by the time you are doing the rawQuery, didn't you want to go for checkDB.rawQuery(... instead?

Regards!